# Como obtener los atributos de un saml response enviados por azure active directory

Tags: python-3.x, azure, google-app-engine, saml

Tengo un saml response que me entrega azure active directory al hacer el proceso con saml 2.0, todo el proceso se hace con normalidad, envio un saml request y office me devuelve el saml response, para hacer todo el proceso me he basado en esta [guia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-non-gallery-applications), he estado leyendo un poco y me he dado cuenta que Azure AD en el saml response envia los valores dentro de este tag:

```
<xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>VALOR AQUI</xenc:CipherValue</xenc:CipherData>
```

Y no dentro de:

```
<AttributeStatement><Attribute Name="IDPEmail"><AttributeValue>administrator@contoso.com</AttributeValue></Attribute></AttributeStatement>
```

como lo especifica en la [documentacion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-saml-idp#sample-saml-request-and-response-messages). La pregunta es, com obtener los verdaderos valores que office me esta enviado y no estos valores encodados, Estoy usando python 3 y google app engine, ademas de como mencione azure active directory y saml 2.0 para hacer el proceso del login, dejo el SAML response completo en esta [url](https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/cbb225f3) por si sirve para dar mejor contexto a mi pregunta.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta (quizás porque no tengo ni idea de saml, aunque sí algo de python por lo que pensé que quizás podría ayudar). Mi duda es si lo que preguntas es cómo extraer información del SAML, lo cual parece sencillo pues al final es un XML que podrías analizar con `lxml` y `xpath`, o si la pregunta es algo más, pues pareces decir que los valores que extrae están "encodados" y no sé a qué se refiere, y no sé si estás preguntando cómo "decodificarlos" (en lugar de cómo simplemente extraerlos)